# How do I fix the legend size in R?

Tags: r, legend, vertical-alignment

My graph:

[image: Legend in plot]

This is the code I used for legend:

```
   legend("topleft", inset(0.05), col = cols, pch = pchs, title="Plot 5", text.width=1.75, legend = levels(tmp$era), box.lty=0, cex=0.3, xpd=TRUE, bty="n")
```

I need to reduce the vertical spaces between the text in legend. How do I fix that?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: `y.intersp` argument?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the argument `y.intersp`:

> vertical (y) distances (in lines of text shared above/below each
> legend entry). A vector with one element for each row of the legend
> can be used.

Here are some examples:

```r
plot(1,1)
# No y.intersp
legend("topleft", inset(0.05), 
       col = "red", pch = 1, 
       title="Plot 5", text.width=1.75, 
       legend = c("Example A", "Example B", "Example C"), box.lty=0, cex=0.3, xpd=TRUE, bty="n")
```

[image]

```r
plot(1,1)
# y.intersp = 0.2
legend("topleft", inset(0.05), 
       col = "red", pch = 1, 
       title="Plot 5", text.width=1.75, 
       legend = c("Example A", "Example B", "Example C"), box.lty=0, cex=0.3, xpd=TRUE, bty="n",
       y.intersp = 0.2)
```

[image]

```r
plot(1,1)
# y.intersp = 0.5
legend("topleft", inset(0.05), 
       col = "red", pch = 1, 
       title="Plot 5", text.width=1.75, 
       legend = c("Example A", "Example B", "Example C"), box.lty=0, cex=0.3, xpd=TRUE, bty="n",
       y.intersp = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Without reproducible data, it is hard to show you the output. But you can trial and error with the `y.intersp` argument.